# How can I process element values in Perl CGI?

Tags: perl, cgi

I want to pass a selected radio button's `id` name and some `div` element data to the server and process those data on the server side.

For an example the below is my CGI code.

```
use strict;
use CGI;
print

"Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n",
"<html>",
"<body>",
"<div style='float:left'>",
"<input type='radio' name='selections' id='red'>",
"<input type='radio' name='selections' id='blue'>",
"<input type='radio' name='selections' id='green'>",
"</div>",
"<div style='float:left'>",
"<div style='float:left' id='redtime'>red time</div>",
"<div style='float:left' id='blutime'>blue time</div>",
"<div style='float:left' id='greentime'>green time</div>",
"</div>",

"<input type='button' value='clickme'/>",
"</body>",
"</html>";
```

In the above CGI file I need to pass the values of the selected radio button's `id` value and any of the `div` elements' data. How do I do that in CGI?

Comment: You need to read something about HTML Forms: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score 3):

The `id` is intended for use client side. If you want to get it server side, then you need to use JavaScript to generate hidden inputs or make the request with XMLHttpRequest.

Use `value` instead.

Then you just:

```
my $value = $instance_of_CGI->param('name_of_radio_group');
```

---

You also need to make your submit button `type="submit"` (which submits a form) and not `type="button"` (which does nothing unless you bind JavaScript to it).

---

Your form controls also need to be placed inside a `<form>` element with the `action` attribute set to the URI of the script that is going to process the data.

---

I also recommend that you put all form labels next to the inputs they relate to *in the markup* and not just with CSS, and that you use `<label>` elements for them, not `<div>` elements.

---

> `"Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n",`

Don't do this manually. You are using CGI.pm.

```
print $instance_of_CGI->header();
```

Comment: Hi Quentin,
How can I call the javascript if I want to validate the radio group before submitting like whether any of the radio has been selected or not?

Comment: @Madhankumar — That's significantly outside the scope of your original question and should be handled in a new question rather than in comments … except it is also a frequently asked question so you should be able to solve it by searching.